# Override Ruby String class method

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'm new to Ruby and am trying to figure this out:

```
class SuperString < String
    def size
        "The Size: " + super.size.to_s
    end
end

a = SuperString.new("My String")
b = String.new("My String")
puts a.size
puts b.size
```

The output is:

```
"The Size: 8"
9
```

Why is one 8 and the other 9?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `SuperString.new("My String").size`,

- `super` calls the method of the superclass, which is `String#size`, and will return `9`, which is the length of the string `"My String"`.
- Next, `9.size` will return `8`, which is the number of bytes used to represent `Fixnum`.
- Finally, `8.to_s` will return `"8"`.

With `String.new("My String").size`,

- `size` will return `9`, which is the length of the string `"My String"`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you called the method .size on the method .super, .super calls to the super class of your class SuperString ( String in this case ), for a method of the same name of the method that you're currently defining.

By calling .size on super you're actually calling .size on the return value of super ( Which is the size of "My String", which is 9 ).

Here's how you want to do the method

```
class SuperString < String

  def size
    "The Size: " + super.to_s
  end

end

a = SuperString.new("My String")
b = String.new("My String")

a.size # => "The Size: 9"
b.size # => 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
an_string = "My String"

class SuperString < String
    def size
        x = super
        p x
        y = x.size
        p y
        z = y.to_s
        p z
        "The Size: " + z
    end
end

a = SuperString.new an_string
b = String.new an_string

puts a.size
p a
puts b.size
p b
```

outputs

```
9
8
"8"
The Size: 8
"My String"
9
"My String"
```

So then I tried:

```
Ezekiels-MacBook-Pro:/Users/tehgeekmeister| irb
1.9.3p327 :001 > 9.size
 => 8 
1.9.3p327 :002 > 8.size
 => 8 
1.9.3p327 :003 > 7.size
 => 8 
1.9.3p327 :004 > 256.size
 => 8 
1.9.3p327 :005 > 1000000000000000000000000000.size
 => 12
```

Basically, 8 is the size of the integer that represents the size.  It's using 8 bytes.  =P